# MySQL: How does AES_ENCRYPT turn the password into a key?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I am trying to figure out how to create the best secure password for AES_ENCRYPT. Specifically, how long should the password be, and how it translates into the 128 bit key length that AES typically uses.

Comment: Are you planning to use `AES_ENCRYPT` to encrypt and then store account or user passwords?

Comment: Well, actually no. Passwords I would store in a one-way encryption with good salt and multiple steps. Other sensitive information requires two-way encryption, I was advised to use AES_ENCRYPT, but I instead plan to AES encrypt before sending to MySQL. But I still have that question,, if AES key length is 128 bits,, how is the password converted to the AES key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems someone else has already found [the answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/mysql-aes-encrypt-key-length/4898#4898) on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)

> Sorry but I found that later from [RubyForum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/182297)
>
> "The algorithm just creates a 16 byte buffer set to all zero, then
>   loops  through all the characters of the string you provide and does
>   an  assignment with bitwise OR between the two values. If we iterate
>   until  we hit the end of the 16 byte buffer, we just start over from
>   the  beginning doing ^=. For strings shorter than 16 characters, we
>   stop at  the end of the string."

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a mysql question, more of a "how does encryption work" question.  If you have some time to kill you might want to watch this series

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlS5_qfxAss&feature=results_main&playnext=1&list=PLDCC9179604F435AB

Here's what I felt was a good explaination of password strength I came across a while back

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9pu3k/how_long_would_it_take_to_bruteforce_crack_an_aes/c0dv7sx

Remember though, the theoretical security of your password is moot if it's stored in source code that is not secure (world readable, ending up in a .mysql_history when working from the commandline, etc).

Comment: Actually, it is not "how does encryption work". Unless I am mistaken, AES encryption would encrypt with a 128 bit (16 byte) key. My question was, how is it that MySQL (and perhaps other databases) convert the password to the 128bit key.

Comment: This question can be tagged a MySQL question. In fact, there is an AES_ENCRYPT function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) in the MySQL Documentation. There is also AES_DECRYPT.